# Efficient memory usage for writing files with digits on ESP32 using MicroPython

Tags: python, arduino, compression, esp32, micropython

As a university project, we have been tasked to perform a 14-hour long experiment, where we need to record changing data from the LDR photoresistor.
We are using A [Huzzah32 esp32](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3405) with the 4 megabytes of disk space and programming it using Micro Python.
We need to leave the machines conducting experiments and gather data from them.

(!) For every measurement, the sensor yields an **integer ranging from 0 to 4095.**

I would like to know, what is the most efficient way to store the experiment data on the machine? The measurements can be repeated very frequently.
Is it a good idea to write a compression algorithm and store them as compressed files? Or is it no efficient to put any additional .py scripts? The specs of my machine are linked.

Comment: How much data are you writing each time (is it just the number from 0 to 4095 or is there more?) and how often is "very frequently"?

Comment: "The measurements can be repeated very frequently." -- what exactly does that mean? Quantify. Is the sensor value the only thing you care about? No timestamps? | Assuming all 4 MiB are available for data, and you use the a simple approach of storing each measurement as a 16bit integer (2 bytes), you can sustain ~ 40 measurements per second for 14 hours... | "what is the most efficient way" -- there is far too little detail here to answer that. You need a thorough understanding of the data to come up with that.

Comment: But looking at that board, I see it has support for adding an SD Card adapter... so why not just do that and store the data on a card (even a cheap one will be orders of magnitude larger than the onboard Flash).

Comment: @romkey its just one number each time :)

Comment: @DanMašek no timestamps. I was thinking about activating sensor with const intervals of time (e.g 0.1 sec), so later for my data presentation ill be able to recreate timestamps myself.

Comment: Yes, fixed sampling rate would simplify things. Feel free to [edit] your question and add all those details. Next thing would be, what do you expect the measured values to look like over time? Are they likely to stay mostly the same, or with only small variations in adjacent samples? In that case delta-coding with some simple variable length codes might help. And perhaps look for some ESP32 port of some simple (not resource intensive) compressor, say LZ4 (might take some work using it from MicroPython). But like I said before, if there's a cheap way to add SD Card, it will be a lot easier.

Comment: The full 4MB won't be available to you. The MicroPython firmware is stored there as well as any modules you're using, and some system overhead.

You know what you're really measuring and I don't; will it actually change fast enough that 10 samples per second is useful?

Have you considered just transmitting measurements to a server and not storing them on the ESP32?

Comment: On esp32 devkit with 4 mb of flash storage user has ~2mb availale (2097152 in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rate is 10 Hz, as indicated in the comments, then you don't need to compress. Storing two bytes per sample will take about a megabyte, and you have two (based on @Lixas comment). So you could go over 20 Hz with no compression.

For higher rates, the first improvement would be to store two samples in every three bytes, since each sample is 12 bits. That will take you to 27 Hz.

To go further, there would need to be some correlation between values. For example, if the light levels change slowly, the differences between successive measurements will be small compared to the full range of 0..4095. You can then take the difference of every sample from the last, and store that instead. You should take a lot of measurements in a representative experiment scenario and make a histogram of the differences. From that you can decide how many bits to allocate a difference that will cover it most of the time. Then you can have a scheme to encode short and long differences. For example, if the differences are almost always less than ±32, then you could get another factor of two compression, and get to over 50 Hz.